# Are partition and volume the same concept?

Tags: partition, storage, volume

From Silberschatz's Operating System Concepts

> A storage device can be used in its entirety for a ﬁle system. It can
>   also be subdivided for ﬁner-grained control. For example, a disk can
>   be **partitioned** into quarters, and each quarter can hold a separate
>   ﬁle system. Storage devices can also be collected together into RAID
>   sets that provide protection from the failure of a single disk (as
>   described in Section 10.7). Sometimes, disks are subdivided and also
>   collected into RAID sets.
>
> Partitioning is useful for limiting the sizes of individual ﬁle
>   systems, putting multiple ﬁle-system types on the same device, or
>   leaving part of the device available for other uses, such as swap
>   space or unformatted (raw) disk space. A ﬁle system can be created on
>   each of these parts of the disk. Any entity containing a ﬁle system is
>   generally known as **a volume**. The volume may be a subset of a
>   device, a whole device, or multiple devices linked together into a
>   RAID set. Each volume can be thought of as a virtual disk. Volumes can
>   also store multiple operating systems, allowing a system to boot and
>   run more than one operating system.
>
> Each volume that contains a ﬁle system must also contain information
>   about the ﬁles in the system. This information is kept in entries in a
>   **device directory** or **volume table of contents**. The device directory (more commonly known simply as the **directory**) records
>   information—such as name, location, size, and type—for all ﬁles on
>   that volume. Figure 11.7 shows a typical ﬁle-system organization.
>
> [image]

I have heard of "partition", but not "volume" before. Are they the same concept? What are their differences and relations?

Comment: They are not the same concept, although both can be used to store a file system. The answer is in the text you quoted: *The volume may be a subset of a device, a whole device, or multiple devices linked together into a RAID set.*

Comment: @jillagre Which of those things can't a partition be?